# Add a string to the beginning of a line containing a pattern

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, vi

I am trying to comment the lines in my scripts where a pattern from a given list of patterns is present. Now, I am able to do it the following way on command line :

```
sed '/abcdefg/ s/^/#/' file.sql > file.commented
```

But if I use a variable for pattern (instead of abcdefg directly as above) I'm not able to do the same.

```
pattern=abcdefg
sed '/$pattern/ s/^/#/' file.sql > file.commented
```

Looks like it is escaping the dollar character and not taking the value of the variable.

How do you do the same with awk?

Comment: Did you waste ten seconds looking for an answer here in StackOverflow? This question has been asked and solved hundreds of times.

Comment: Well, sorry about that. But I searched for it yesterday too and tried different things before spending/wasting my time here. I will delete the question.

Comment: @AjimBagwan: Don't delete the question since answer with non-regex options has been posted below, that might help other readers on SO.

Comment: @AjimBagwan: In my opinion once you asked it, there is no need to delete it because some users took their time to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use double quote to make it work with variables in shell:

```
sed "/$pattern/ s/^/#/" file.sql > file.commented
```

You can also use inline feature of shell to save changes in input file itself

```
sed -i.bak "/$pattern/ s/^/#/" file.sql
```

**However it is best to avoid `sed` for this job** since it uses regex and above command will break if `$pattern` contains `/` or some special regex meta character. Better to use `awk` like this:

```
awk -v p="$pattern" 'index($0, p) {$0 = "#" $0} 1' file.sql > file.commented
```

Comment: Damn it! I tried that but overlooked it, thinking that it didn't work. But it works. Thanks.

Comment: How do you do the same with awk?

Comment: You're welcome, see my updated answer and consider using `awk` over `sed` because of the reasons I stated above.

Comment: I have already provided equivalent awk command in the answer.

Comment: The awk version is only printing the matching line (with a # in front of it). It isn't redirecting the non-matching lines as it is to the file, the way sed does. What exactly does index($0,p) do?

Comment: Please check updated answer for edited awk command. `index($0,p)` finds string `$pattern` in `$0` (which is one full line in file)